# Is it possible to provide access to mongodb instance hosted in aws ec2(private subnet) via an ELB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I need to be able to give access to a mongodb instance running inside a aws ec2 instance(private subnet) in most secure way. So I thought of granting access to this mongodb instance by putting it under an ELB.

I have create a target group for port 27017 and have added the ec2 instance as targets. Security groups of ec2 instance allow access to 27017 to 0.0.0.0/0

ELB is exposed to outside via port 80 and 443 and forwards all requests to target group available on port 27017.

But I'm unable to access this instance via ELB domain. Tried accessing this via MongoCompass client.

Comment: It is better to use a reverse proxy instance in this case. Launch a micro EC2 instance and configure a proxy, like HA Proxy, Nginx or use Rinetd for simple port forwarding.

Comment: @vikyol thanks for the recommendation. I'll give it a try